# Применить стиль к виджету

Tags: gwt, java, css

Можно ли применить стиль (CSS) к определенному виджету (`PopupPanel`), а не к элементу? Ведь `PopupPanel` разворачивается в обычный div.

P.S. Не к экземпляру, а для всех экземпляров этого виджета.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в css файле проекта переопределить классы

> .gwt-PopupPanel
>
> .gwt-PopupPanel .popupContent

то эти изменения коснутся всех PopupPanel, кроме тех, на которых было применено stylePrimaryName(свойство в UiBinder'е или методом где то в Java коде) с иным стилем.

Comment: Таким образом работает. Но нужно писать не только класс, но и тег

    div.gwt-PopupPanel {
        ...
    }

Иначе по приоритету не проходит.